# Difference between "orthogonal distance regression" and "total least squares"

Tags: regression, total-least-squares

I'm trying to figure out the difference(s) between total least squares (TLS) and orthogonal distance regression (ODR). Both techniques are used when there is error in the dependent variable. Per [this blog post: Total Least Squares in comparison with OLS and ODR](https://towardsdatascience.com/total-least-squares-in-comparison-with-ols-and-odr-f050ffc1a86a) ODR allows for the specification of error in each individual data point, whereas errors are the same for all dependent data points in TLS.

My question: if you set all errors the same in ODR, is it the same as TLS? In other words, is TLS a special case of ODR?

Comment: TLS can have any number of predictor variables, whereas according to http://www.mechanicalkern.com/static/odr_ams.pdf, ODR deals with a single predictor.

Comment: Thanks. Does the equal weight version of ODR equal the 1D version of TLS then?

Comment: I guess yes.$\,$

Comment: ODR can have multidimensional outputs as well. That paper was just an introductory text. The complete ODRPACK manual covers the full range of capabilities. See section 2.C.iii. for an example. http://mechanicalkern.com/static/odrpack_guide.pdf